# Как определить цвет пикселя в который попал raycast

Tags: c#, unity3d

вы не знаете можно ли определить цвет пикселя в который попал raycast. Типа мы выстрелили в объект raycast-ом и
попали в него, можно ли определить цвет пикселя в который мы попали.

Comment: ну вот вроде дока есть [ссылка](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RaycastHit-textureCoord.html) , но там используется SetPixel. можешь попробовать использовать метод GetPixel

Comment: сомнительный механизм, а если объект не был отрисован по той или иной причине? или финальный цвет пикселя на экране был изменен пост процессингом или антиалиасингом?

Comment: Вы лучше напишите зачем Вам это.